# Как улучшить читабельность класса класса модели?

Tags: java

Имеется класс Юзера, и пришел ответ на тестовое задание, что как можно улучшить читабельность этого класса? Собственно вот сам класс:

```
public class Employee {

private int employeeId;
private String name;
private boolean empActive;
private int dpId;
private Department department;

public Employee(int employeeId, String name, boolean empActive, int dpId, Department department) {
    this.employeeId = employeeId;
    this.name = name;
    this.empActive = empActive;
    this.dpId = dpId;
    this.department = department;
}

public Employee() {
}

public int getEmployeeId() {
    return employeeId;
}

public void setEmployeeId(int employeeId) {
    this.employeeId = employeeId;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public boolean isEmpActive() {
    return empActive;
}

public void setEmpActive(boolean empActive) {
    this.empActive = empActive;
}

public int getDpId() {
    return dpId;
}

public void setDpId(int dpId) {
    this.dpId = dpId;
}

public Department getDepartment() {
    return department;
}

public void setDepartment(Department department) {
    this.department = department;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Employee: \n" +
            "employeeId = " + employeeId +
            ", name = " + name + '\'' +
            ", empActive = " + empActive +
            ", dpId = " + dpId +
            ", department: " +department;
}
```

}

Comment: Можно использовать билдер вместо конструктора с кучей параметров.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Переименовать имена членов так, чтобы не было сокращений типа `dpId`.
- Использовать [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/), который позволит не писать все эти геттеры и сеттеры.

Answer (score 1):

1. Упростить наименования полей, лишние слова ни к чему: `employeeId`
   -> `id`, `empActive` -> `active`.
2. `dpId` - что это? Если это department id, то лучше его переместить
   внутрь класса `Department`, в противном случае - дайте ему более
   человеческое имя.
3. Для метода `toString` можно сделать еще более читабельным - замените его на 
   `return String.format("Employee:\n id = %d, name = %s, active = %s, dpId = %d, department: %s", id, name, active, dpId, department)`.